# How to cature screenshot of parralex website with sticky navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, webpage-screenshot

Hope you guys doing great. I want to capture whole screen of website (from top to bottom) but failed. It is a **parallax site template** with **sticky navbar** and when i try to capture screen it actually repeat background images and sticky navbar.

What i tried so far:
fireshot, iweb2.0, Chrome and Mozilla's built in screenshot plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use windows Screen Capture ?

All you have to do is press

> ALT + Prnt Scrn

keys together. It will help you to take screenshot of your Active Screen then go Paint and use Paste so you can easly do any editing you like.

**If your page is longer then one page I suggest you to use Print to File (as PDF or XPS). 
Now you have a full webpage in your hand now  all you have to do is Export it to jpg or png.**

I hope I understand your question properly and answered your question.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. Yeah i did but i want entire page to be capture. It capture only the visible area not the whole page.

Comment: @ScorpionPk I updated my answer , I hope it helps you.

Comment: tried this method too but it brings white background with duplication of images. And see someone down voted my question.

Comment: OK after printing as pdf then export as a image you have a chance to edit it by any image process ; there should be applications for this but I hate installing applications when I have a solution . Btw I upvoted be cool :D